# Error [Sitefinity Nuget] Unable to load the service index for source [Progress Sitefinity]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022, sitefinity

I have added the `http://nuget.sitefinity.com/nuget` in the Package Source Manager of Visual Studio 2022, according to the documentation here: [SiteFinity Documentation](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/install-sitefinity-in-.net-core-mode#configure-sitefinity-nuget-repository), but it's not getting the package info from the server.

[image]

> Error
> [Sitefinity Nuget] Unable to load the service index for source http://nuget.sitefinity.com/nuget.
> The content at 'http://nuget.sitefinity.com/nuget' is not a valid JSON object.
> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the https version of the feed: https://nuget.sitefinity.com/nuget/

Comment: Same Issue, Doesnt work.

Comment: can you access that url in the browser?